# Microsoft Project Server - Must Haves

Tags: project-management, project-server

**Question:** What should I look for in a candidate for a position of EPM Consultant?

[Wiki says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_project_management)

> Enterprise Project Management (EPM), in broad terms, is the field of organizational development that supports organizations in managing integrally and adapting themselves to the changes of a transformation.

I know that it stands for ePM is enterprise project management; but these(ePM and Project Server) are two different things. EPM is a methodology, while Project Server is a tool, probably to implement that. But, I am not sure how does it relate to Microsoft Project Server?

I have been tasked to hire an EPM Consultant for MS Project Server 2010.

Thanks for sharing your thoughts, in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that EPM stands for Enterprise Project Management, and that it is a methodology for managing projects across an entire enterprise. And that Project Server is an application that is designed to support EPM.

Microsoft sought to align their branding of their Microsoft Office Project Server solution (an integration of Project Professional (client/desktop), Project Server (one of the first of their business apps built on a SharePoint platform) with EPM by calling Project Server 2007 'Microsoft EPM'.

Microsoft is referring to Project Server 2010 more often as PPM - 'Project Portfolio Management'. This reflects the fact that Project Server 2010 now includes Portfolio Server (previously a separate, but integratable app), Excel Services, and other integrated services which provide a full set of integrated Business Intelligence features. 2010 enables organizations to apply more portfolio selection and management strategy to their enterprise project management capabilities.

In order to get the full value from EPM, you need a system that can support your methodology. In order to get the full value out of Project Server, you need to develop and implement a consistent EPM methodology. They have to work together.

[removed self-promotion]